# Get all subdomain of a top level domain with python

Tags: python, dns, subdomain, google-search

I want to list all subdomain of a given second level domain.top level domain (2LD.1LD) , such as `.edu.uk`, or `.gov.us` by python

I use `dns` package in python

```
import dns.resolver

answers = dns.resolver.query('stackoverflow.com', 'MX')
for rdata in answers:
    print('Host', rdata.exchange, 'has preference', rdata.preference)
```

But it can't work with `dns.resolver.query('edu.uk', 'MX')`

I also use `googlesearch`

```
from googlesearch import search
res = search("site:edu.uk",num_results=1000)
print((res))
```

But it only responses 100 results.

I want a result that have all subdomain (I think it's a very big result). How can I do? Thank all

Comment: Your question is not really about programming, as Wes explained. But for "I want a result that have all subdomain " it could have been useful to explain why you need that. And if it is in general (any TLD), or some specific ones for specific reasons. For example, if it is for some kind of research, you can possibly argue for it with the registry, and they might give you access to relevant data. Or not. All depends what you have exactly in mind, before even attempting to solve the problems with technical solutions.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer: you can't.  There is no way to query an entire domain's contents, regardless of level.  Some (only a few, like the root) allow you to transfer the zone using AXFR transfers (try: `dig @b.root-servers.net axfr .` if you have the bind utilities install).  But in general, the DNS protocol does now allow you to always get the contents of a tree of DNS records.  You can guess at some of them, for example you figure above that there might be `MX` records inside some zones which is frequently true (exception example: no TLD has an `MX` record).  You can guess that most domains do have a `www` prefix with an `A` or `AAAA` record, but  even that can't be assured.

In short: your issue isn't with python, its with the DNS protocol itself.  There is no way, in any language, to get a complete list of zone contents if the owner of that zone doesn't want you to.

[side note: DNSSEC signed zones with NSEC proof of non-existence records allow you to "walk" a zone for the names of the records, but I don't suggest you generally try to abuse this feature -- we run a DNS scanner and even we don't use this approach when looking for signed domains -- it would cause a lot of legitimate hate email]

Comment: Just to add that not all registered domains are published, so even if you could get all the DNS data, either through AXFR, opendata, list of daily published names, NSEC walking, whatnot, you still don't get all registered names. Just the published ones. There is no clear statistics on the difference, but I would use a ballpark of 1 to 5% of names registered but not published. Depending on why the list of "all" names is needed, this can be important, or not.

Answer (score 0):

Some websites have a /robot.txt to list urls for google to crawl through. If you are allowed a alternative is using burpsuite and a subdomain list to scan through them.

Comment: 1) `robots.txt` gives directives to robots to crawl/not crawl relevant parts of the sites 2) so I think you are mixing things up with `sitemap.xml` which indeed is intended to list "all" URLs on a website for search engines to find them (you know there is more than one search engine out there, no need to focus on one), but 3) all of that does not even start to give ideas of "all domains under a given TLD". If you have a specific idea in mind you might want to expand your answer because as it stands it does not answer at all the question exposed.

Answer (score 0):

Search any domain on google and type in site:example.com